# при уменьшении экрана пропадает часть текста

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

вопрос такой как правильно сделать, чтобы не обрезалось пространство?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>CVSCenter_QuickGuide</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="inner-left">
            <li class="btn toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Введение"><span class="tocnumber"></span>
                    <span class="toctext">Введение</span></a></li>
            <li class="btn_2 toclevel-1 tocsection-2"><a href="#Общие_положения"><span class="tocnumber">1</span>
                    <span class="toctext">Общие положения</span></a></li>
            <li class="btn_3 toclevel-1 tocsection-3"><a href="#Алгоритм_действий"><span class="tocnumber">2</span>
                    <span class="toctext">Алгоритм действий</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="btn_4 toclevel-2 tocsection-4"><a href="#Предварительная_настройка"><span
                                class="tocnumber">2.1</span> <span class="toctext">Предварительная
                                настройка IP камер</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="btn_5 toclevel-2 tocsection-5"><a href="#Установка_комплекта"><span
                                class="tocnumber">2.2</span> <span class="toctext">Установка комплекта программного
                                обеспечения</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="btn_6 toclevel-2 tocsection-6"><a href="#Добавление_камер"><span
                                class="tocnumber">2.3</span> <span class="toctext">Добавление камер в серверную часть
                                комплекса</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="btn_7 toclevel-2 tocsection-7"><a href="#Настройка_подключения"><span
                                class="tocnumber">2.4</span> <span class="toctext">Настройка подключения датчиков /
                                реле</span></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-right">
            <div class="un_1 " style="display: none">
                <h1> <span class="mw-headline" id="Введение">Введение</span><span class="mw-editsection"></h1>
                <div class="unit_1">
                    <p>
                        Для того, чтобы облегчить чтение, в предлагаемом руководстве используются следующие
                        соглашения о шрифтах и графических обозначениях:
                    <p><span class="bold">Полужирный</span> – названия систем CVS.</p>
                    <p><span class="bold_curs fst-italic">Полужирный курсив</span> – названия и определения в
                        системах CVS.</p>
                    <p><span class="fst-italic text-decoration-underline">Подчеркнутый курсив</span> – названия
                        элементов управления в программах CVS.</p>
                    <p><span class="text-decoration-underline">Подчеркивание</span> – общепринятые названия или
                        определения.</p>
                    <p><span class="fst-italic">Курсив</span> – названия …</p>
                    <p><span class="numer">
                            <ul>
                                <li>– списки и перечисления</li>
                            </ul>
                        </span></p>
                    </p>
                    <p> Так же в тексте используются графические обозначения:</p>
                    <div class="otstup_1">
                        <p><img src="img/1.png" class="lft rounded float-start px-3" alt=""></p>
                        <p class="mlft">Такой знак обозначает информацию, на которой стоит
                            заострить внимание и учитывать в дальнейшем при работе с
                            системами CVS.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="otstup_2">
                        <p> <img src="img/2.png" class="lft rounded float-start px-3" alt=""></p>
                        <p class="mlft">Такой знак означает замечания или рекомендации, к которым необходимо
                            прислушаться для
                            достижения оптимальной производительности и стабильной работы программно- аппаратных
                            комплексов.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="otstup_3">
                        <p> <img src="img/3.png" class="lft rounded float-start px-3" alt=""></p>
                        <p class="mlft">Такой знак обозначает примечание, на которое следует обратить
                            пристальное внимание!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="un_2" style="display: none">

                <h2> <span class="mw-headline" id="Общие_положения">1 Общие положения</span><span
                        class="mw-editsection">
                </h2>
                <div class="unit_2">
                    <p> <img src="img/1.png" class="lft rounded float-start px-3 py-3" alt=""> </p>
                    <p class="tblft ">Системы CVS как с аналоговыми камерами, так и с IP
                        камерами работают под управлением операционных систем
                        семейства Windows (x86, 32 bit и x64, 64 bit):
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows 7</span>,</p>
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows 8</span>, <span
                            class="text-decoration-underline">Windows 8.1</span>,</p>
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows 10</span>,</p>
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows Server 2008</span>, <span
                            class="text-decoration-underline">Windows Server 2008 R2</span>,</p>
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows Server 2012</span>, <span
                            class="text-decoration-underline">Windows Server 2012 R2</span>,</p>
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows Server 2016</span>,</p>
                    <p class="tblft"><span class="text-decoration-underline">Windows Server 2019</span></p>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="unt_2">
                    <p> <img src="img/1.png" class="lft rounded float-start px-3 py-3" alt=""></p>

                    <p class="tblft "> Внимание !</p>

                    <p class="tblft ">Все действия должны производиться оператором с административными правами в
                        операционной
                        системе.</p>

                    <p class="tblft ">Разработчики систем CVS подразумевают, что у пользователя имеется опыт в
                        администрировании
                        операционных систем Windows.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="un_3" style="display: none">
                <h2> <span class="mw-headline" id="Алгоритм_действий">2 Алгоритм действий</span<span
                            class="mw-editsection">
                </h2>

                <p>Всё актуальное программное обеспечение систем <span class="bold">CVS</span> находится на
                    сайте cvsnt.ru странице сайта
                    <span class="fst-italic">«Центра загрузки»</span>
                </p>

                <p class="llft"> https://www.cvsnt.ru/support_soft.html</p>

                <p> На этой странице имеются ссылки на архивы с программным обеспечением и руководствами для
                    пользователей.</p>

                <p><span class="bold">CVSCenter 7</span> — программный комплекс компьютерных телевизионных
                    систем обеспечения безопасности
                    <span class="bold">CVS ( Computer Video Security )</span> —
                    единое программное обеспечение как для видеосерверов, так
                    и для клиентских рабочих мест.
                </p>

                <p>Инсталлятор находится в архиве ZIP</p>

                <p class="llft">https://www.cvsnt.ru/soft/cvs_v720.zip</p>


                <p>Для дальнейшей работы необходимо провести инсталляцию (установку) программного обеспечения на
                    компьютере.</p>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="fst-italic">Видеосервер</span> — на компьютере, к которому будут
                        подключаться камеры,
                        устанавливается комплект программного обеспечения CVSCenter и настраивается
                        серверная часть ПО: подключения к видеокамерам, микрофонам, обработка
                        получаемых медиаданных, запись архивов, поддержка работы клиентских приложений
                        — <span class="bold">CVS Авто</span> или <span class="bold">CVS Авто+</span>, <span
                            class="bold">CVSAutoServer</span>, <span class="bold">CVSMap</span>, <span class="bold">CVS
                            FaceDetector</span>, <span class="bold">CVS Mobile
                            Server</span> и др.
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                        <span class="fst-italic">Видеоклиент</span> — на компьютере, который будет подключаться
                        к видеосерверу
                        (видеосерверам), устанавливается комплект программного обеспечения CVSCenter и
                        настраивается клиентская часть ПО: для просмотра и прослушивания медиаданных в
                        режиме онлайн, просмотр и прослушивание ранее записанных архивных данных.
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="unt_3">
                    <p>
                        <img src="img/3.png" class="rounded float-start px-3" alt="">Программное обеспечение
                        CVSCenter позволяет на одном ПК
                        одновременно работать как серверной части, так и
                        клиентской.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tst.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

css

```
Обнуление

{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

*,*:before,*:after{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:focus,:active{outline: none;}
a:focus,a:active{outline: none;}

nav,footer,header,aside{display: block;}

html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
input,button,textarea{font-family:inherit;}

input::-ms-clear{display: none;}
button{cursor: pointer;}
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding:0;border:0;}
a, a:visited{text-decoration: none;}
a:hover{text-decoration: none;}
ul li{list-style: none;}
img{vertical-align: top;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:inherit;font-weight: 400;}


/*--------------------*/

body
{
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.parent 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.inner-left 
{
     width: 150px;
     /* outline: 1px solid #060; */
}

.inner-right 
{
    flex-basis: 150px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    /* outline: 1px solid #900; */
    background: firebrick;
}

.otstup_1 
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative;
}

.otstup_2 
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
}

.otstup_3 
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
}

.lft 
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block
}

.mlft 
{
    padding-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 3cm; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block
}

.unt_2 
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
}

.tblft
{
    padding-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 3cm; 
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

/* .un_2 
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
} */

.unit_2 
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
}

.llft
{
    padding-left: 2%;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: 600;
}

.bold_curs 
{
    font-weight: 600;
}

.unt_3
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
}

.otstup_4
{
    padding-bottom:  20px;
    /* position:relative */
}

.cntr 
{
    text-align: justify;
}

.un_4_1
{
    padding-bottom:  50px;
    position:relative
}

.check::before
{
    content: "✓";
}

.image-container 
{
    max-width: 1169px;
    /* height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
   width: 100%; 
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  justify-content: center; */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1321px) 
{ 
    image-container 
    {   
        width: 90%;
    }   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1260px) 
{ 
    image-container 
    { 
        width: 80%;
    }   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1230px) 
{ 
    image-container 
    { 
        width: 70%;
    }   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 412px) 
{ 
    image-container 
    { 
    width: 10%; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: у тебя в html теги где-то не закрываются, нужно поправить. Также нужно какое-то демо, чтобы было понятно где косяк.

Comment: например, <h1> <span class="mw-headline" id="Введение">Введение</span><span class="mw-editsection"></h1> ======> последний span не закрыт